# SUPEE 7405: Add Form Key to sidebar/default.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, template, security, supee-7405, form-key

After installing SUPEE 7405  my custom theme Sidebar Cart stopped deleting products. When delete button is clicked, throws an error: "Cannot remove the product".
Looks like I need to add Form Key to the sidebar cart delete button code.
Located in the custom theme.
I think form key should look like this:

```
form_key/<?php echo $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>
```

/frontend/CUSTOMTHEME/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml

```
<a href="<?php
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if($params['isAjax'] == 1){
            $refererUrl = Mage::registry('referrer_url');
            if (empty($refererUrl)) {
                $refererUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
            }
            $deleteUrl = $this->getUrl(
                'checkout/cart/delete',
                array(
                    'id'=>$_item->getId(),
                    Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl($refererUrl)
                )
            );
        }else{
            $deleteUrl = $this->getDeleteUrl();
        }
        echo $deleteUrl; 
    ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
```

Please help me out adding the form key. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. And this is how you do it:

#### Replace

```
$deleteUrl = $this->getUrl(
    'checkout/cart/delete',
    array(
        'id'=>$_item->getId(),
        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl($refererUrl)
    )
);
```

#### with

```
$deleteUrl = $this->getUrl(
    'checkout/cart/delete',
    array(
        'id'=>$_item->getId(),
        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl($refererUrl),
        Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I've replaced the code as you've mentioned however the Ajax cart no longer adds any products to the cart. In other words, when I click "Add Product", the Ajax pop-up box is stuck at loading/adding product, but no product is added.
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ah, Magento 1.7 doesn't have the `Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY` constant yet, replace that with the literal string `'form_key'`

Comment: To confirm, the line should look like this?: 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()

Comment: yes, cnofirmed.

Comment: Great solution, works perfectly, MANY THANKS!